# How to match and replace sections of a string in SQL

Tags: sql, regex, vertica

I'm pulling a list of popular sites from my database, but I want to combine results that are from the same domain. I've been able to do this partially by using :

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(site, '%|^www([123])?\.|^m\.|^mobile\.|^desktop\.')) as site
```

so that "www.facebook.com" and "facebook.com" or "m.facebook.com" 
- all of which appear in the database - are treated as the same when I do a `select distinct`.

However, I want to take this a step further by writing an expression that looks at each string between periods. If a match is found consecutively in three or more strings between periods, then I want to treat those as the same. I simply can't predict every possible string that could come before "facebook.com", or any other site.

**So for example:**
"my.careerone.com.au" and
"careerone.com.au" match in three places.

Or "yahoo.realestate.com.au" and "rs.realestate.com.au" match in three places.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**@David** code will work in Vertica as well but not so well performance wise maybe.

You can use Vertica's own internal functions such as `TRIM & REGEXP_REPLACE`.
After *borrowing* **@David Faber** reg exp i endend-up with this.

```
select TRIM(LEADING '.' from REGEXP_REPLACE(col_name,'^.*((\.[^.]+){3})$', '\1')) AS fixed_dn from table_name;
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Could you break down the regex? I'm still relatively new to them, so I just want to be able to see what everything does in my head.

Comment: Hi @TradorDave take a look at this link http://www.regexr.com/ - you will learn how to build your own reg experssions, it explain all of that very clear.

Comment: I've been trying this out a bit more, and it has one small issue... I still want it to remove 'www.' in all instances regardless of how many periods are in the URL. If I change it to `trim(leading '.' from REGEXP_REPLACE(site, '^.*((\.[^.]+){3})$|^www([123])?\.', '\1'))`, then it replaces 'www.' with '\1'. So 'www.facebook.com' becomes '\1facebook.com'.

Comment: Ok, I've now figured out that it needs to be like this: `trim(leading '.' from REGEXP_REPLACE(site, '^.*((\.[^.]+){3})\1$|^www\.|^m\.'))`... however, I still need "facebook.com" to match with "facebook.com.au", and "home.facebook.com". If I change the `{3}` to `{2}`, then it matches anything with ".com.au" or ".co.nz", which I don't want.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have Vertica available so I tested this in Oracle SQL (which does have `REGEXP_REPLACE()` that is similar to Vertica's). Not sure what the CTE syntax would be in Vertica but you'll be querying against a table anyway:

```
WITH d1 AS (
    SELECT 'my.careerone.com.au' AS domain_nm FROM dual
     UNION ALL
    SELECT 'careerone.com.au' FROM dual
     UNION ALL
    SELECT 'yahoo.realestate.com.au' FROM dual
     UNION ALL
    SELECT 'rs.realestate.com.au' FROM dual
)
SELECT domain_nm, TRIM('.' FROM REGEXP_REPLACE(domain_nm, '^.*((\.[^.]+){3})$', '\1')) AS domain_nm_fix
  FROM d1;
```

What `REGEXP_REPLACE()` does here is trim the highest level subdomains from the domain name, if it exists and if there are more than 3 levels. If there are only three levels then nothing will be replaced as the regex won't match -- that is why the leading `.` character then has to be trimmed. So, for example, `careerone.com.au` will be unaltered, while `my.careerone.com.au` will be changed to `.careerone.com.au` by the `REGEXP_REPLACE()`, from which the leading `.` then has to be trimmed.